# Shareware computer game where you play a starfighter pilot

Tags: story-identification, video-games

For those who were born after the mid 90's, shareware games were games that the first chapter you got for free or real cheap and, if your curiosity was piqued, you bought the rest later.

In this game you play a human mercenary starfighter pilot in a distant, fictitious solar system you travelled around fighting enemy spaceships on missions. The perspective of the game was a sort-of "bird's eye" view, as if you looked straight down on the action.

There were some encounters where you had spoken dialogue with pilots of other ships- the first encounter in the game you had was with a smug alien who who said that the player's craft alone was no match for it in combat but "30 or more" like it might be a threat.

In a crude cinematic at the beginning of the game there was writing that said the humans of this system were distant relatives of people on Earth but I never got far enough to figure out how.

Some of the other games that came with this were made by a company called Apogee, so it's possible this game was made by them as well.

Comment: +1 for the introductory paragraph. Kids these days... :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you're talking about...

**Solar Winds**
By Epic MegaGames

You're a mercenary in it, flying a fighter spaceship in a kind of top-down view. There's a smug bastard who thinks he's better than you. And the intro talks about humans from a solar system in a distant galaxy being distant relatives of us.

And even though it isn't Apogee, Epic Megagames was a huge part of that same era of games. Also, that game was awesome.

Here's a YouTube video.

Comment: "*that game was awesome*" -- yes it was!

Comment: Remember buying this from a store as a kid - the shareware version that is. Always the funniest quirk of shareware that anybody could print and sell their own copies.

Comment: @razethestray:  I have a recollection of a "shareware vending machine" at a Blockbuster Video in the mid-90s.  You brought your own diskette, paid a nominal fee, and selected the desired shareware program from a menu.  I think I got the shareware version of [Dark Ages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Ages_(1991_video_game)) this way.

Comment: Crazy that both this and Strike Commander both came out the same yeah, with dramatically different graphical capabilities.